# RVM Ruby on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I installed RVM and then the most recent version of Ruby with it. Now when I try to generate a new rails app I get the following error message.

```
    NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
    Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
    NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
    Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
    NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
    Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.1.gemspec:11.
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [rake-0.8.7, rake-0.8.7, rubygems-update-1.8.1] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site

/1.8/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have the rails gem actually installed for your RVM installation:

```
gem install rails
```

Otherwise, it will default to run the version of Rails pre-installed on Snow Leopard (the `/usr/bin/rails` file)

All of the deprecation messages you're seeing are just warnings; the latest version of RubyGems deprecated a **lot** of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add on to this...

I had the same problem. I tried installing rails several times. If someone else comes across this and should the above not work, it was a matter of giving the directory proper permissions. Details:

I'm running Rails on Mac OS 10.6.8. In my user directory I like to setup a Projects directory for my dev work. I was able to run rails just fine after chmod-ing the Projects directory to 777.

I hope this helps.